# Select multiple div in one selector in jQuery

Tags: jquery

On my page: XXXXXXXXXXXX

I have 5 `div` with class: `listing` and each `div.listing` has one div with class: `clinic_values` and each `div.clinic_values` has one `p` element.

Example:

```
<div class="listing">
 <div class="clinic_values">
  <p>Some text</p>
 </div>
</div>

<div class="listing">
 <div class="clinic_values">
  <p>Some text</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

When I use selector `jQuery("div.clinic_values")` at line 89 in script: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

It works fine, but when I use selector: `jQuery("div.listing div.clinic_values p")` in line 89:

```
jQuery("div.listing div.clinic_values p").each(function (index) {
```

the code fails. I need to select all `p` elements that are inside `div.clinic_values` and those `div.clinic_values` that are inside `div.listing`.

Because there are other `div` in page with class `clinic_values` that are not inside `div.listing`. Those should not be selected. Only those `div.clinic_values` should be selected that are inside `div.listing`.

How do I do that?

Comment: it works: https://jsfiddle.net/5c81tgqe/2/

Answer (score 2):

You need to for each by div.listing and get inside div. that div is clinic_values. and for each again by clinic_values and get p tag.

```
$(document).find("div.listing").each(function (){
   $(this).find("div.clinic_values").each(function (){
      $(this).find("p").text();
   })
})
```

Comment: i posted 2nd post.

Comment: I assume You didn't mean to post twice.  Instead of posting 2 answers, you should update your original answer using `edit`.

Answer (score 0):

`jQuery("div.listing").children("div.clinic_values").children("p").each(function() { ... })` should work

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class=listing>
  <div class=clinic_values>
    <p>Address</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class=listing>
  <div class=clinic_values>
    <p>Address</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class=not-listing>
  <div class=clinic_values>
    <p>Address</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class=not-listing>
  <div class=clinic_values>
    <p>Address</p>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
let listings = ['a', 'b', 'c'];



jQuery("div.listing div.clinic_values p").each(function(index) {

  jQuery(this).html(function() {
    return jQuery(this).html().replace("Address", listings[index]);
  });
});

</script>
```

Comment: use the script bellow the html, also `class=not-listing` or `class=listing`